# How can I do the same animation like in Google Play or Chrome omnibox on Android when I scroll

Tags: android, google-chrome, animation, google-play

How can I do the same animation that Google Chrome on Android and Google Play have. The effect that I want is when I scroll the Action Bar disappears but smoothly, how can I do that?

Example: (sorry but I can't upload videos here)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7otV-_1sdEvaGFVbzY5cy0wX1VpNEJzNzQ3bXhDTXljR1d3&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

There is official documentation on how to achieve this effect: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html.

To enable overlay mode for the action bar, you need to create a custom theme that extends an existing action bar theme and set the android:windowActionBarOverlay property to true.

**Enable Overlay Mode**

*For Android 3.0 and higher only*

If your minSdkVersion is set to 11 or higher, your custom theme should use Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*For Android 2.1 and higher*

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on devices running versions lower than Android 3.0, your custom theme should use Theme.AppCompat theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Specify Layout Top-margin**

When the action bar is in overlay mode, it might obscure some of your layout that should remain visible. To ensure that such items remain below the action bar at all times, add either margin or padding to the top of the view(s) using the height specified by actionBarSize. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I used the same method as you mentioned above, but there's a problem is that, when entering a new page and I quickly make a fling gesture, the animation seems not that smooth, because we should first change the layout topMargin, after that we then let the WebView scroll, it's there any better way to do that?